# Adding / to end of URL takes user to random page and on other pages strips images

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, tracking

I'm working on a site here:

Now if you add a / to the end of the URL the images vanish, this means I cannot place Google adwords tracking code on the end of any URL's:

It takes you to a totally different page, this is the one it is supposed to show:

Even if you only put a / at the end it takes you to another page!

Any one see this before, any fixes?

Comment: Can you give an example (by providing before and after URL's) of when a URL goes to a random page when you add a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your website URL ends with `.aspx` and not `.html`, you don't need the `/` before the `?utm_source` and the rest of the code.

Removing the `/` in all of the tracking codes would fix your problem.

Regarding the fact that `/` in the end of your website URL (trailing slash) causes the images in your site to disappear, read this:

> A trailing slash should not be added to a URL with a file extension 
>   (i.e. one should not use http://example.com/post/Nikon-Lens-Rentals.aspx/ ).
>
> Beyond the root
>   path, it is arguable if a trailing slash  should be added to URLs
>   without extensions. If trailing slashes are are added for a site,
>   the site needs to  take into account the scenarios when trailing
>   slashes are not provided by users or referrers, and the site needs to
>   perform a 301 redirect to the appropriate URL.

When you append a slash at the end of any aspx page it does not generate 404 but rather displays the same page without any CSS or images in it because IIS treats the file as a folder rather than as a page.